# how to access MSMQ in web proxy class

Tags: wcf, proxy, msmq

I've created a wcf web service hosted on IIS 5.1. In the service implementation class there is a method GetAlarm which access the MSMQ on that system. In a sample win form application i instantiate web proxy to call GetAlarm method. But the problem is that when i use GetAlarm method using proxy for local machine then it propmts error like "**he queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation**.". While i've given all the users full permission in corresponding queue users (properties/security). I can access the rest of methods using web proxy but not msmq.

If i use the GetAlarm method without proxy then it works fine.

please help;

arvind

Answer (score 0):

You say "I've given all the users full permission".
What permissions did you give and to which accounts?

An easy test for security issues is to temporarily give "Everyone" and "Anonymous Logon" Full Control to the queue. If that works then it is a permissions issue.

If you have given the permissions to the account that you think is accessing the queue but still get access denied then you could enable security auditing on the queue to check what account is actually being used.

Also see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758627/how-to-access-message-queue-msmq-via-wcf

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: You have functionality in a DLL that puts a message on an MSMQ queue and you want to be able to use that functionality from a WCF service

Comment: suppose a case where MSMQ is deployed on Machine-1 with user name User-1

form other Machine-2 with user name User-2 i call a method using wcf proxy for Machine-1

please let me know in that case for which user i need to give permission on Machin-1 to able to use MSMQ by called mwthod using wcf proxy requested from Machine-2. And how can i do that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any experience of WCF.
Were you able to get success by giving "Everyone" and "Anonymous Logon" Full Control?